# Get string between patterns, copy to the end of the line, and add another string to the copied string

Tags: sed

I have a huge list of files i want to add to a lightbox galery. I generated the thumbnail image, all i need is to make sed grab everything from "foto" to "bmp" "jpeg" or "jpg" or "png" (some of my images have their extension caps locked, like PNG, JPG JPEG BMP) and add to the end of the line with a `-thumb` before the extension.

Making this

```
<a href="images/foto (1000).jpeg" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/
<a href="images/foto (950).bmp" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/
<a href="images/foto (10).png" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/
<a href="images/foto (100).JPG" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/
```

Look like this

```
<a href="images/foto (1000).jpeg" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/foto (1000)-thumb.jpeg
<a href="images/foto (950).bmp" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/foto (950)-thumb.bmp
<a href="images/foto (10).png" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/foto (10)-thumb.png
<a href="images/foto (100).JPG" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/foto (100)-thumb.JPG
```

I have been able to get things between patterns, and add things to the end of the line, but I can't do this work.

Comment: Is there a typo at the end of the second line of expected output? Have you copied across `<a href="images` by accident?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be too dirty for what you want, but here's one way using `GNU awk`:

```
awk -F '["./]' '{ print $0 $3 "-thumbs." $4 }' file.txt
```

Results:

```
<a href="images/foto (1000).jpeg" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/foto (1000)-thumbs.jpeg
<a href="images/foto (950).bmp" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/foto (950)-thumbs.bmp
<a href="images/foto (10).png" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/foto (10)-thumbs.png
<a href="images/foto (100).JPG" rel="lightbox[galeria]" title="Description."><img src="images/foto (100)-thumbs.JPG
```

Comment: Works pretty well. Thanks. Had to change it to make it work on Windows' gawk `gawk -F "[\"./]" "{ print $0 $3 \"-thumbs.\" $4 }" file.txt` Thanks